# pictures unlimited for each list

Tags: django

I want to solve the problem for an unlimited number of pictures for each list. Whenever I want to put the pictures on the list, I get only one picture or i write several fields for the picture.

Note: Photos are added at the same time as the list

I try define ForeignKey for picture and then store ids in session

```
class Listing(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
class Photo(models.Model):
  image = models.ImageField(default="default.png", blank=True, null=True, upload_to="photos/%Y/%M/%D")
  listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, related_name='Photos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
  if request.method == "POST":
    myfile = request.FILES['file'] if 'file' in request.FILES else False

    if myfile:
      photo = Photo.objects.create(image=myfile)
      if not 'saved' in request.session or not request.session['saved']:
        request.session['saved'] = [photo.id]
      else:
        request.session['saved'].append(photo.id)
```

but when print all ids in session show no all ids in array session

```
      for session in request.session['saved']:
        print(session)
```

just two ids With I uploaded more than two files

39
43
[22/Aug/2019 15:10:55] "POST /For_Sale_Post HTTP/1.1" 200 32

Comment: you should save the file in a temporary location (to storage) and only save the file path in the session. You can't put a file in a session. I actually have a temp image model where I save the image and only keep the id in the session. Then when saving the final result, I copy the files to the final model and delete the temp ones.

Comment: How is it......

Comment: i try to save file into database and save id in session but no response correct for all ids picture

Comment: you need to update your question to show the code you're trying and show the error you're getting.

Comment: The problem is still not resolved

Comment: But your `Photo` model requires a `listing` fk (you haven't set `null=True`) so how can `Photo.objects.create(image=myfile)` not throw an error?

Comment: i remove line and problem sill
listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, related_name='Photos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: Please, give me the model you use with thanks

Comment: Note that there's an issue with concurrency. If you're uploading multiple files quickly and multiple requests are processed in parallel, your changes to the session are going to clash.

Comment: How are users uploading the files? One at a time? Or you create multiple requests in parallel in javascript?

Comment: one at a time and send request ajax the problem is get first id and last and Ignores others, I mean whenever I upload a file, it prints the id beginning of session, the id of the uploaded file last id,  and Ignores others.Please, give me your code

Comment: are users logged in? when you say 'one at a time' you mean the user waits for the response, then uploads the next picture?

Comment: i slove problem thank you

Comment: after `request.session['saved'].append(photo.id)` add `request.session.modified = True`.

Comment: thank you i use:
 
` 
else:
        saved_list = request.session['saved']
        saved_list.append(photo.id)
        request.session['saved'] = saved_list
`

Comment: That also works because when you assign a value to a session key Django knows it changed and will save it. The problem with appending directly is that no change is detected. But `modified=True` solves that elegantly.